# Using Sci-Kit learn to classify text with a large corpus

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

I have about 1600 articles in my database, with each article already pre-labeled with one of the following categories:

```
Technology
Science
Business
World
Health
Entertainment
Sports
```

I am trying to use sci-kit learn to build a classifier that would categorize new articles. (I guess i'll split my training data in half, for training and testing?)

I am looking to use tf-idf, as I don't have a list of stop-words (I can use NLTK to extract only adjectives and nouns, though, but i'd rather give scikit-learn the full article).

I've read all of the documentation on scikit-learn, but their examples involve word-occurence and N-grams (which are fine), but they never specify how to tie a piece of data to a label.

I've tried looking at their sample code, but it's too confusing to follow.

Could someone help me with this, or point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: @larsmans I'm not sure where to start, is the issue. All of the documentation i've read (which is all of it) doesn't seem to apply to labeled data. I am looking for someone with more experience to point me in the right direction.

Comment: There are several document classification examples in the [example gallery](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/), and many of the other examples are about classification as well.

Comment: First, SVM a.ka. support vector machine. Sci-kit learn can be made to work with Pandas and integrated well with a variety of classifiers (e.g. Naive Bayes which is a good choice or LDA for which I actually recommend Pattern). See https://gist.github.com/zacstewart/5978000.  You can even create your own vectors. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html. It's all based on distance (Euclid, tf-idf + cosines;etc. and some form of clustering). Feature extractors are available if necessary.

Answer (score 13):

I think you faced the same problem I did when I started to feed my own data to the classifiers.

You can use the function `sklearn.datasets.load_files`, but to do so, you need to create this structure:

```
train
├── science
│   ├── 0001.txt
│   └── 0002.txt
└── technology
    ├── 0001.txt
    └── 0002.txt
```

Where the subdirectories of `train` are named as the labels, and each file within the labels directory is an article with that corresponding label. Then use `load_files` to load the data:

```
In [1]: from sklearn.datasets import load_files

In [2]: load_files('train')
Out[2]: 
{'DESCR': None,
 'data': ['iphone apple smartphone\n',
  'linux windows ubuntu\n',
  'biology astrophysics\n',
  'math\n'],
 'filenames': array(['train/technology/0001.txt', 'train/technology/0002.txt',
       'train/science/0002.txt', 'train/science/0001.txt'], 
      dtype='|S25'),
 'target': array([1, 1, 0, 0]),
 'target_names': ['science', 'technology']}
```

The object returned is a `sklearn.datasets.base.Bunch`, which is a simple data wrapper. This is a straightforward approach to start playing with the classifiers, but when your data is larger and change frequently, you might want to stop using files and use, for example, a database to store the labeled documents and maybe having more structure than just plain text. Basically you will need to generate your list of categories (or `target_names`) like `['science', 'technology', ...]` and assign the `target` value for each document in the `data` list as the index of the labeled category in the `target_names` list. The length of `data` and `target` must be the same.

You can take a look to this script that I wrote time ago to run a classifier: https://github.com/darkrho/yatiri/blob/master/scripts/run_classifier.py#L267

Comment: I'm trying to load a custom dataset which is similar to the example you have taken and I need to create train and test dataset. I am getting similar results as above. 
I tried splitting using train, 'test = train_test_split(data, train_size = 0.8)' but that is returning an error. What do I do?
I have asked question here in detail: goo.gl/bpp9mn

Answer (score 2):

Maybe start with the example here: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html#example-document-classification-20newsgroups-py

A somewhat more advanced example is this:  http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html#example-grid-search-text-feature-extraction-py

There are quite a few more text examples in the example gallery:
http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/index.html

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look at those. I want to be able to use my own data, how can I preprocess it for use with scikit?

Comment: If it is plain text it should be good to go. Scikit-learn expects the training data to be a list of documents. Just read all the files and create a list of their content.

Comment: How can I pass the labels of the documents into scikit?

Comment: Edited to point to the more feature-rich 20newsgroups example. @Yoni201 as the `y` argument to fit.

Comment: @larsmans So I need two arrays, one with all of my documents in some order, and the second with all of my labels in the order that corresponds with the documents?

Comment: Also, how would I load my own categories in this case? It seems like they're being loaded from some file.

Comment: Yes. Maybe `sklearn.datasets.load_files` is of help. Otherwise, you'll have to code something up yourself.

Comment: ``y`` just needs to be a list of categories, in the same order as the articles in the input.